# How do I convert this ECDF representation function from MATLAB into Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing, tuples

I have to convert the following MATLAB code:

```
% calculate ECDF from D at n points
function X = ECDF_representation(D, n)
  m = mean(D); X = [];
  for d=1:size(D,2),
      [f, x] = ecdf(D(:,d)+
          randn(size(D(:,d)))*0.01);
       ll=interp1(f,x,linspace(0,1,n),'cubic');
       X=[X ll];
   end
   X= [X m];
end
```

into Python. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF

def ecdf_representation(D, n):
    """calculate ECDF from D at n points"""
    m = np.mean(D)
    X = []
    for d in xrange(D.shape[1] + 1):
        f, x = ECDF([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d])) * 0.01])
        ll = interpolate.interp1d(f, x, np.linspace(0, 1, n), 'cubic')
        X = [X, ll]
    X = [X, m]
    return X
```

I get the error:

```
in ecdf_representation
for d in xrange(D.shape[1] + 1):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If I switch the line `for d in xrange(D.shape[1] + 1):` to `for d in xrange(D.shape[0] + 1):`

I resolve the original error but get a new one that is:

```
line 25, in ecdf_representation
f, x = ECDF([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d])) * 0.01])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

EDIT:

`D` is a 1-d array because of the value being returned in the following function where `data` is a pandas data frame.

I think I should be returning something else into the `ecdf_representation` function, but I'm not sure what.

```
def segment_energy(data, th):
    mag = np.linalg.norm(data.loc[:, ['x', 'y', 'z']], axis=1)
    mag = np.array(mag)
    mag -= np.mean(mag)

    above = np.where(mag >= th * np.std(mag))
    indicator = np.zeros(mag.shape)
    indicator[above] = 1
    plt.plot(mag)
    plt.plot(indicator * 1000, 'r')
    plt.show()
    return indicator
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the input data itself.  If you're getting a tuple out of range for the shape, that means that the data is 1D when the MATLAB function is 2D.  What is the data coming in?  Set a breakpoint or figure out what the size of the data is by doing `print(D.shape)` prior to the rest of the code running.  Also, `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` returns **an interpolation function**, not the actual interpolated values so your method of calling it is incorrect.

Comment: Should I use `scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator ` instead? What should I pass in as the arguments in that case?

Comment: I also get an error with the line ` f, x = ECDF([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d])) * 0.01])` being an `unhashable type`

Comment: No you can still use `interp1d`.  What you would do is first create the function: `func = interpolate.interp1d(f, x, kind='cubic')`.  Once you create this, call the actual function to produce the interpolated data: `ll = func(np.linspace(0, 1, n))`.  Also that error you are getting is all driven by your input `D`.  I can't say anything more until I know what it is.

Comment: I realized I am returning a 1d array. I need to figure out what I'm supposed to be passing in instead. I'll edit my question with the other function.

Comment: The MATLAB code states that `D` is a 2D array and you are iterating over each column individually.  You are using that `ECDF` function on each column.  You'll need to structure your input so that it's a 2D array.  I don't know what this 2D array contains so I can't provide any more context.